# I can't connect to CouchDB UI in other computer

Tags: couchdb

After I loaded the couch database and confirmed connecting localhost with port 5984. I want to access this web console in other computer. But It doesn't work. I changed every other ports and checked the firewall. But those didn't have any problems. Is there anybody got same experience?

Thanks in advanced.

Another question,

For changing the web port in local.ini and killed the previous loading application, but why does the previous one alive? Is there any command to unload/stop the application? I can't find the command in bin directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the parameter `bind_address` in the config from `127.0.0.1` (accessible from localhost only) to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know it? Could you explain about this?

Comment: It's a configuration issue which occurs often. You have sorted out all other possible reasons like the firewall. As you know the first time CouchDB installation starts with a `admin party` configuration. For security reason the CouchDB is accessible from localhost only in this state.